# Skipping test cases programmatically if the method or class is decorated with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute

Tags: c#, xunit, testcase, skip

We have a project (in C# with xunit as a testing tool) where few classes and few methods are decorated with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute but test cases are written for that class or method. This results in pipeline taking much more time for running.

As few methods are excluded from code coverage, the respective test cases do not play any role in the code coverage result.

We need to skip the test cases run for those methods/class where ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute is present. Currently there are more than 500 methods with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute in different files, it is quite impossible to go to each and every method with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage and check the reference in test project to mark it as skip.

**So is there any way to exclude them programmatically.**

Below scenario

Class c1 has methods c1m1, c1m2 , c1m3. But c1m2, c1m3 are decorated with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute.

Class c2 has methods c2m1, c2m2 , c2m3. But c2m2 is decorated with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute.

Class c3 has methods c3m1, c3m2 , c3m3.But  class c3 is decorated with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute.

Class c4 has methods c4m1, c4m2 , c4m3.

Test Class for class c1 is c1Test and has validate_c1m1, validate_c1m2 , validate_c1m3.

Test Class for class c2 is c2Test and has validate_c2m1, validate_c2m2 , validate_c2m3.

Test Class for class c3 is c3Test and has validate_c3m1, validate_c3m2 , validate_c3m3.

Test Class for class c4 is c4Test and has validate_c4m1, validate_c4m2 , validate_c4m3.

Need to skip the execution of test cases with ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute